# Upper bound for density of standard Brownian Motion

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, density-function

I need to prove the following: if $\{W_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is standard Brownian motion under the measure $\mathbb{P}$, then for $x>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[W_t \geq x]=\int_x^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-y^2/2t} \,dy \leq \frac{\sqrt{t}}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2t}.
\end{align}
I think I need to use integration by parts, but I don't really know which functions to pick. Does anyone know how to proceed or how to prove this otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_x^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}/2t} dy=\int_x^{\infty} \frac  1 y ye^{-y^{2}/2t} dy \leq \frac 1 x \int_x^{\infty} ye^{-y^{2}/2t} dy $. Now $\int_x^{\infty} ye^{-y^{2}/2t} dy =-t (e^{-y^{2}/2t})|_x^{\infty}=te^{-x^{2}/2t}$. Divide by  a suitable constant to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can you derive this inequality you mention?

Comment: @Jason I just used the fact that $\frac 1 y <\frac 1 x$ when  $y >x$.

Comment: Thanks. But how do we know that $y > x$?

Comment: @Jason You are integrating w.r.t $y$ from $x$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I see. Thanks, it was simpler than it looks in the end.

Comment: One more question, in the evaluation of the integral, why is there an "x" in front of the e power and not a "t"? We are integrating over y right?

Comment: Why are we not using the points $y=\infty$ and $y=x$ instead, since we're integrating over $y$ and not over $t$? I get $te^{-x^2/2t}$.

Comment: Well, my calculation is just the following: $\int_x^{\infty} y  e^{-y^2/2t} \,dy = -t \int_x^{\infty}e^u \, du = -te^u |_x^\infty = -te^{-y^2/2t} |_x^\infty = te^{-x^2/2t}.$ However, your result is $xe^{-x^2/2t}.$. So I get the impression you made a typo (or my calculus is wrong, but wolfram yields the same). Anyway, it doesn't matter for the question I asked, it's just a minor detail.

Comment: @Jason Sorry. Your calculation is correct. I have edited the answer.